# How to do I convert an escaped t into a tab character

Tags: perl, escaping

I have a variable that contains a slash and a `t`.

```
my $var = "\\t";
```

I want to convert that to a tab. How do I do that?

---

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Term::ReadLine;
my $rl = Term::ReadLine->new();
my $var = $rl->readline( 'Enter \t:' );
print Dumper $var;
```

Comment: (`s/\\//` removes the slash, leaving `t`, not a tab.)

Comment: See also [String::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Escape)

Comment: [String::Unescape](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Unescape) is also a slightly more direct solution to this general problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the simplest solution:

```
 $var = "\t" if $var eq "\\t";
```

If you want to do this no matter where the sequence appears in the string, you could use

```
 $var =~ s/\\t/\t/g;
```

But it sounds like you're not asking the right question. Nothing supports `\t` and nothing else. At the very least, I would also expect `\\` to produce `\`. Are you perhaps trying to parse JSON? If so, there are number of other escape sequences you need to worry about.

Comment: So, broken by design, then. There's no way to specify one wants `\ ` followed by `t`.